# My assembly assign two number to int and want to print it. But when run, it says Segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, printf, x86-64, calling-convention

Here's the code

I tried insert subq $8. %rsp before call printf@PLT, and it runs well. But I wonder why this happen?  (I use gcc to compile)

```
.text
.section .rodata
.LC0:
.string "%d\n"
.text
.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
subq $8, %rsp
movq $5,-8(%rbp)
leaq .LC0(%rip),%rdi
movq -8(%rbp),%rsi
call printf@PLT
leave
ret
```

I expected the output of 5 but it is Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: The stack needs to be aligned to a multiple of 16 bytes on entry to a function.  By subtracting 8 from the stack pointer, you destroy this alignment, causing `printf` to crash.

Comment: But I can let it run well if i add movq $0, %rax before call printf@PLT, and don't do anything otherwise, why? @fuz

Comment: That's because this tells `printf` that you do not pass any floating point arguments and your implementation of `printf` might not use any instructions that assume an aligned stack in this particular execution.  Do not assume that it's going to keep working though.  Read the [ABI document](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) for details.  There is a common duplicate for this exact question, let me try to find it.